# Are there any wp plugins to join css files into one file?

Tags: wordpress

My site load many css files, and it was slow. Are there any wp plugins help join multiple css file into one big css files?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the w3 total cache plugin, enabling the "minify" option after activating it: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/